# ubuntu make install location

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-10.04, file-location

When we,

```
./configure
make
make install
```

where are the programs installed?

Answer (score 13):

As Dirk notes, the default prefix is "/usr/local"; however, you can change it. For example:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/local
make
sudo make install
```

Note, though, that you should not install software in this way. You should use Ubuntu's package management system called `apt-get` to install software. You should only use configure+make+make install if there is no apt-get repository containing a package for it. The reason you should use apt-get is that it automatically manages dependencies and versioning of software and will ensure that your software is automatically updated. Installing things manually is a good way to show you do not care by introducing dependency conflicts or a good way to have outdated, possibly vulnerable software on your system. So, before you install something that way, you should use `apt-cache search` to find out of a package already exists, and then you can use `sudo apt-get install` to install it. Example:

```
apt-cache search boost # This will show all sorts of packages related to Boost
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev # Ok, this is the one on the list I want
```

Comment: in particular, building your own stuff with PREFIX=/usr most definitely counts as "doing it wrong" and will break your system in the long run.

Comment: You can also add the prefix on the `make install` step -- that is how `.deb` packages are configured for `/usr/` but installed to temporary directory where they are packaged up from.

Comment: @hobbs Is it okay to use this way to build a library (like libjpeg) and not break things? I am in the impression that the `make install` step just copies built files to the specified folder prettily.. which should be safe. (?) Can you please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Default `prefix` (or `destdir`) is `/usr/local` unless that has been overridden in the `autoconf` logic.

You can often override this in the `make install` step too.